# $p=(1-\zeta_{p})...(1-\zeta^{p-1}_{p})$

Tags: number-theory

Let $\zeta_{p}$ be a primitive $p$th root of $1$. Then $t^{p}-1=(t-1)(t-\zeta_{p})(t-\zeta_{p}^{2})\ldots(t-\zeta_{p}^{p-1})$. Using this, I need to show that $p=(1-\zeta_{p})\ldots(1-\zeta^{p-1}_{p})$ but I do not know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by $t-1$, use that $\frac{t^p-1}{t-1}=1+t+\dotsb + t^{p-1}$ and then evaluate your equation at $t=1$.

---

For an alternative, you can evaluate the derivation of both sides at $t=1$.

Comment: Seeing as this incorporates both of the other answers, I'll select this one. I KNEW it was about $\frac{t^{p}-1}{t-1}=1+t+\ldots+t^{p-1}$! Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

$$(t-\zeta_{p})(t-\zeta_{p}^{2})\ldots(t-\zeta_{p}^{p-1})=\frac{t^p-1}{t-1}=1+t+t^2+...+t^{p-1}$$

plug in $t=1$.

Answer (score 2):

A small hint:
$\frac{d}{dt} = ... $, and let $t=1$.

Comment: Even as "a small hint" (in fact it would be a rather big one if it were clearer), you should at least tell **what** to differentiate...